# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads, advertising

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting Drupal tools
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3606).

Comment: Thanks @Grace Note, just what I needed!

Comment: @Grace Is it possible to promote camps only for a certain timeframe. Fx Drupal 2 days in Feb wont be relevant after it has been held.

Comment: @googletorp Yes, there's been several like that. Just delete them after the event has taken place.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Join Drupal's Community on Reddit - r/Drupal]

Answer (score 7):

[image: If you want Rules for D8, then checkout and/or support #d8rules]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: I think it would be good to get this ad to +6 votes.

Answer (score 4):

[image: PlaceToBe for Drupal module recommendations]

Comment: Please note that this is a repost of [this (now deleted) answer](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/community-promotion-ads-2016/3440#3440) to a similar question from 2016. Credits go to [Tom](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/users/59223/tom) (for posting that last year). Apart from re-posting it here now, I reused the very same image, and only adapted it to address the rejection (deletion) reasons from last year. Anybody who wants to do so, feel free to improve/replace the image (hopefully not the clickthrough-url). Disclosure: I'm a reviewer there ...

Comment: I don't like the wording of this. To me this seems like some one is unhappy with on/off topic policies of Drupal answers, and not as some one who want to advertise Software recommendations (SR). An add to SR seems like a fine idea, but the overall messaging needs a major overhaul imo.

Comment: Highlight what's good about SR and why the user would want to go there. the whole setup with pretending the using want to ask a question which you can answer but are not _allowed_ to ask on DA seems very negative to me and also a bad way of selling SR (it's a lot more than that I guess).

Comment: Also please don't ask me to do your work for you, it's you who want this community add, not me. I was just kind enough to tell you why I think the add in it's current form is bad for DA.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Facing DevOps challenges with Drupal? There is an SE-site for it!]

Comment: Rest assured, you'll find some familiar DA.SE-usernames over there also already, such as [**user 3**](http://devops.stackexchange.com/users/3) (close to "user/1", right?),  [**user 288**](http://devops.stackexchange.com/users/288),  [**user 476**](http://devops.stackexchange.com/users/476) ... and also [me](http://devops.stackexchange.com/users/40).

Comment: This is an interesting one. I wonder if we have any closed questions here that would be good migrations. I know we have closed some Drupal in Docker questions, but I don't know about the quality. A meta question there may be a good idea to help seed things some more with cherry picked closed questions.

Comment: So - Maybe link to the site directly: http://devops.stackexchange.com/,  don't add your referrer code for a proposed DA add.

Comment: You should use the link you write on the image, not area 51

Comment: Nobody that didn't follow that proposal can now create an account, until the proposal doesn't go in public beta. That is what private beta means. I am deleting this post until the proposal is its public beta phase.

Comment: The previous comment is not correct: it takes a little extra effort to find the correct link, but during private beta anybody can actually create an account on such site.

Comment: Update: [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)'s public beta started a few minutes ago (and I updated the clickthrough-url in the ad to its official URL now).

Comment: It would look better without the squiggly red spelling-check underline.