# Why are the Community promotion ads 2017 no longer showing up?

Tags: bug, advertising

Unless I'm missing something, I have the impression that none of the qualifying "[Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516)" are being displayed on drupal.SE, and this for (I estimate) about 1 to 2 weeks already.

What happened, why are they no longer shown? If my impression is correct, please have them show up again.

Disclosure: I'm the author of some of those ads ...

Comment: Looks like it's fixed, I am seeing them.

Answer (score 2):

Shog9 told me:

> This is a side effect of
>   [All sites will be switching Ad Servers on October 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301524/all-sites-will-be-switching-ad-servers-on-october-1).
>   A fix should be rolling out by 2017/11/27 or so.

Comment: The link is interesting, but I don't get it how this is "a side effect of ...". Can you include a relevant quote from that link to better explain what you mean?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Sorry, I don't have much more info.  I asked about it, and that is almost an exact quote from Shog and I didn't ask for any more details.  I assume that when they switched to DFP that some of the community ads broke or were overlooked.

Comment: Moving from Adzerk to DFP means that our ads are now being served in `<IFRAME>` elements, rather than being written directly to the parent page's DOM. Due to iframe sandboxing and browser security issues, we have to refactor these ads to support being served in a standalone environment, as opposed to assuming they have access to any of the parent page's environment (CSS/JS issues, mainly).

Comment: source: I'm the dev fixing this stuff :)

Comment: @rossipedia merci for the clarification, ***that*** explains what's happening. However, how come this issue has not been addressed BEFORE moving away from Adzerk? Moreover, how difficult would it be, as a temporary workaround (for as long as you need to get the fix in production), to copy/paste the qualifiying ads into whatever it takes to make them show up "as if some company bought some ad-space"? In other words: if a company contacts SE with "hey, can I buy adds to show up ASAP", how long would it take to "deliver" those ads? PS: has this been **tested** before going live?