# Enable Community Promotion Ads for 2018

Tags: feature-request, advertising

Quote from "[Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516)":

> We reset the ads once a year, every December.

And another one from it:

> It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

My question: please reset / cycle the community promotion ads from 2017, ideally by ... yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Per the SE team, this should be happening around the last week of January or first week of February.

Comment: Which ***year***, and why not right away? January is already about to be finished ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens 
I assume Shog meant 2018CE. No reason was given for the delay.